# How to find a value in an array after a value is stored in it from a text file?

Tags: java

I have a code which will read Strings from a text file and store it in a String array. Then the user would enter a String and check if it exists inside the array. Sadly it always print an error

> Name not found on my database :<.

Where did I go wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

class MaleNames{
    static String names[] = new String[1362];
    static Scanner readFile;
    static String n;
    static int i = 0;
    static int x = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        try {
            readFile = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/James Vausch/Desktop/MaleNames.txt"));
            System.out.println("");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Could not locate the data file! Please check the address of the file.");
        }
        readFile();
    }

    public static void readFile() throws Exception{
        while(readFile.hasNext()) {
            names[i] = readFile.next();
            System.out.println((x + 1) + ". " + names[i]);
            x++;
            i++;
        }
        checkName();
    }

    public static void checkName() throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Enter a name so that we can check that on my database. :3");
        n = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
        for(int j = 0; j < 1362; j++){
            if(n.equalsIgnoreCase(names[j])){
                System.out.println("Name found on my database :>");
                break;
            }else{
                System.out.println("Name not found on my database. :<");
                System.out.println(names[1000]);
                break; 
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Do you want to search for another name? Yes or No?");
        String ask = new Scanner(System.in).next();
        if(ask.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")){
            checkName();
        }else{
            closeFile();
        }
    }

    public static void closeFile() {
        readFile.close();
    }
}
```

Here I also have sample names to be saved on a text file (MaleNames.txt):

```
Joshua
James
Theodore
Thewa
Adrian
```

It should find the String inside it's array and print

> Name found on my database

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
for(int j = 0; j < 1362; j++){
    if(n.equalsIgnoreCase(names[j])){
        System.out.println("Name found on my database :>");
        break;
    }else{
        System.out.println("Name not found on my database. :<");
        System.out.println(names[1000]);
        break; 
    }
}
```

This code will break out of the loop at the first name that *doesn't* match, which is always the first name (unless you happen to enter the first name in the list).

Instead, you could check *all* the names and break only when you *match* the target name, or save yourself a lot of pain and code by just doing this instead of your loop:

```
if (Arrays.asList(names).contains(n)) {
    System.out.println("Name found on my database :>");
} else {
    System.out.println("Name not found on my database. :<");
}
```

Better still, use a `Set<String>` instead of a `String[]` to hold your names, in which case the test just becomes:

```
if (names.contains(n))
```

As a general rule, use collections in preference to arrays.

---

If this is an assignment that specifies that collections (and streams) are not to be used, you would have to do something like this:

```
boolean found = false;
for (int j = 0; j < names.length && !found; j++){
    found = n.equalsIgnoreCase(names[j]);
}

if (found) {
    System.out.println("Name found on my database :>");
} else {
    System.out.println("Name not found on my database. :<");
    System.out.println(names[1000]);
}
```

Comment: I got your point. The code is also working. Thanks a lot for the help. Much appreciated.

Comment: @MannJaeger You’re welcome. if this “answers your question”, you should [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it.

Comment: I certainly do. Thanks a lot by the way @Bohemian